# Poll with changing amount of file descriptors

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, nonblocking

In my program UDP sockets are stored in a limited size array, socke can be removed from the array which results in a restructuration of the array to keep it sequential.

I wan't to create a thread waiting for a certain message on those sockets and I would like to use non-blocking I/O for that task.

My problem is that the array of socket can change over the time, using poll if I wan't to take those changes in account I need to modify the array of `pollfd`. But, if `poll` is already called how can I make it take those changes into account?

I still could use a timeout but I find that solution not really good because it's kind of like a "non satisfying receptor" (I hope it's the right word in english).

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't change descriptors set while  you are polling on it, nor proper design should call for it.

Comment: I agree it sounds like a bad design choice, but like most slow system calls `poll()` will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR` when a signal is delivered, so you could raise one when you need to change your array.

Comment: There's also the `ppoll` function wich take signals into account, this might be the solution but I'm trying to figure out how it works...
I have set the sigmask to `SIGUSR1` and I send that signal with `pthread_kill` to the corresponding thread, but this cause the program to close because of the signal sent. So I have set `signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN)` in my main but this cause the program to do nothing after `pthread_kill`, and `ppoll` doesn't quit.

Comment: The question I would have is:  why is thread A trying to modify a data structure (the sockets array) that thread B is using?  You'll get more reliable behavior if you don't try to share resources across threads like that.  So for example if thread A wants to remove a socket from the array, it shouldn't do that itself; rather it should ask thread B to do it.  (thread A can request that thread B do so by adding an appropriate request-message-item to a mutex-protected FIFO queue, and then waking thread B up, at which point thread B can drain the FIFO queue and handle the requests in it)

Comment: You're right, that is probably what I will do after figuring out how ppoll works (or why I can't make it work), and then how to to know from `ppoll` if it has been interrupted by a signal or a filedescriptor event. Then it would be possible. I find `ppoll` poorly documented.

Comment: In your example thread B still needs to perform non-blocking IO on each sockets, so `ppoll` seems the best solution.

Comment: Side Note: Consider using a statically sized array. Reconstructing the array seems to me like a waste of operations related to events that probably happen very often. You can probably get better performance by using a fixed size array with flags for active/inactive descriptors.

Comment: It is, I meant that insertion and deletion are performed on the array, after deletion the last element is swap with the deleted one to keep it sequential.
Anyone ever encountered the same problem with `ppoll`? Maybe I should open a new subject, there's absolutely nothing on the web about it and manual doesn't respond to my problem...